# Variable creation within a program

Tags: variables, python-3.x

Next, in my quest to learn Python I've come across a question. Can a variable be created inside a program, named by concatening strings, and used to store an object?

So, my object:

```
class Veg:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.name = x
        print('You have created a new vegetable:', self.name, end='\n')
```

Now, to create a variable:

```
tag = 1
newVegObj = 'veg' + str(tag) #Should create a variable named 'veg1'
newVegObj = Veg('Pepper') #Creates an object stored in 'newVegObj' :(
```

But I want the object created to be stored in 'veg1'. Then I can do:

```
tag = tag + 1
newVegObj = 'veg + str(tag) #Create a variable named 'veg2'
newVegObj = Veg('Tomato')
```

The goal is for veg1.name = Pepper and veg2.name = Tomato, and to able to continually create additional variables to store additional vegetables.

I don't know if this is possible or not. If so, and if this requires a complicated solution, could you please provide a helpful explanantion of code employed? Hopefully its something simple that I'm just not thinking about.

Thanks in advance! You guys are the best!

Comment: No, you're wrong. You don't want that. You want a dict, maybe. Or a list.

Comment: You just deleted an object. You created a veg and then when you stored it in newVegObj, you got rid of the reference to the old one...

Comment: Maybe if you tell us what you're really trying to do SO could help; it seems like you're actually trying to achieve something through an obscure feature...

Comment: What I'm trying to build is a bunch of objects, each a different 'vegetable' that stores lots of individual data. Then list all the objects in a menu, with the ability to continually create more entries, and access each entry to make changes to the data within. The more I think about this and what you guys are saying, it sounds like a dictionary would be more appropriate, but as I'm learning, I got to the section that talks about objects. I thought objects would be more efficient because you can create infinite numbers of objects. I can't figure out how to store each new entry in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your comments, something like the following might prove useful.

```
names = ['Tomato', 'Snoskommer', 'Pepper'] # a list containing 3 names
vegetables = {} # an empty dictionary

for name in names: # just textual: for each name in the names list ...
    new_veg = Veg(name) # create a new vegetable with the name stored in the variable 'name'
    vegetables[name] = new_veg # add the new vegetable to the vegetable dictionary

# at this point, the vegetables dictionary will contain a number of vegetables, which you can find by
# 'indexing' the dictionary with their name:
print(vegetables['Tomato'].name) # will print 'Tomato'
```

Hope that helps to undestand some basics in Python, though starting at a simple tutorial might be best :)

---

To extend, something like the following could be made to change things later:

def add_vegetable(name):
    if name in vegetables:
       print('There is already a vegetable with that name...')
    else:
       vegetables[name] = Veg(name)

Calling the function to add a vegetable to the list:

```
add_vegetable('Cucumber')
```

After which the dictionary will contain another vegetable named 'Cucumber'.

But again: go through some introductary tutorials, http://python.org should be able to point you to some.

Comment: That does help a lot! Thank you! :) Obviously I was on the wrong track. I have been trying to learn this stuff from three different books, and I have zero programming experience. So from your answer, to add a new vegetable, I would just need to .append that veggie to the list. From there it gets created as an object and added to the dictionary?

Comment: Not automatically; the `for` loop is what the thing that adds new vegetables to the list. Please note that the code above is *only* to demonstrate something about a list and a dict, the snippet is functionally quite useless. To add a new vegetable to the list you could use a function, for example.

Comment: I will check out the tutorials on your advice. I think I follow your explanation though. Thanks for the help!